# Explain the program logic in javascript to make a single checkbox selected when all other checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript

```
function check(){
  var xx =document.getElementById("of");
  var box = document.getElementsByName("chk");

  for(var i=0 ; i<box.length;i++){

    if(box[i].checked == true){
      x=x+1;
    }
    if (x == box.length){
      xx.checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Here `check`  is the `onclick` function of checkboxes that is selected by the user.The name of the checkboxes are "chk".

Here "xx" represent the checkbox that want to be selected automatically when all other checkboxes are select

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, I've added comments to your code:

```
function check(){
  var xx =document.getElementById("of");
  var box = document.getElementsByName("chk");

  // Loop over all the checkboxes
  for(var i=0 ; i<box.length;i++){
    
    // If the box is checked....
    if(box[i].checked == true){
      x=x+1;  // Increase a counter
    }
    
    // If the counter is equal to the amount of checkboxes....
    if (x == box.length){
      xx.checked = true;  // Make the "of" checkbox checked
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable x is not defined.

```
   function check() {
        const checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("chk");
        const toBeChecked = document.getElementById("of");

        //initialize a counter
        let counter = 0;

        //loop over all checkBoxes
        for (let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
            //check if current checkBox is checked and increment counter
            if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        //check if all checkBoxes are checked and if so set the other checkBox to set
        if (counter === checkBoxes.length) {
            toBeChecked.checked = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've modified the OP code and introduced new syntax to it, but you overlooked that the OP doesn't understand the original code in the first place. Why would your modified code make more sense?